# sort nested dict with sum of nested key values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

So I am trying to sum the values of nested keys and sort the key values by this value. I have a nested dict like the following:

```
dict_items([('“The', {'T': 1}), ('reason', {'T': 1}), ('we', {'T': 1, 'O': 1}), ('have', {'T': 1, 'O': 1}),...
```

I want to sum the values associated with the keys `'O'` and `'T'` and then sort the words `The`, `reason`... by the values produced by summing each of their `'O'` and `'T'` values so that I get a dict back with the word and its value.

So far I have the following which returns the counts of the words but not the words attached:

```
sorted([sum(i[1].values()) for i in dct.items()], reverse=True)
```

I have tried the following, but I get a key error with 'O'

```
my_word_dct = sorted(dct.items(), key = lambda x: x[1]['O'] + x[1]['T'], reverse = True)
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

EDIT: The expected output would be something like:

```
{'we':2, 'have':2, 'The':1, 'reason':1...}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you trying to sort the dict (possible after python3.7 only) or do you just want a list of keys in sorted order? An indication of your expected output would help.

Comment: ah yes! Added in edit at bottom

Comment: Dictionaries are generally not ordered, do you need to sort it? How about just doing `d2 = {k : sum(d[k].values()) for k in d}`

Comment: Ah nice! This looks good to me. Thanks

Comment: What if they had the same sum?

Answer (score 0):

You want the .get() function in case your dictionary doesn't have the key in question.

```
x[1].get('O',0) + x[1].get('T',0)
```